# Calculate Date Duration

Tags: momentjs

I have to calculate the duration of two dates with days and hours remaining.

If the two dates have different days, I need to return the duration in days and hours.

For example, given the following input:

> `2016-12-11T09:30:00.000Z`  and `2016-12-12T11:30:00.000Z`

I would like to have this output:

> 1 day 2 hrs

How to achieve this using moment.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in.

Just create moment object from your strings/dates, then get the difference in milliseconds using [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method in order to create a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object. Use `format` method from [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) to print duration according your needs.

Here a working example:

```js
// Create moment objects
var m1 = moment('2016-12-11T09:30:00.000Z');
var m2 = moment('2016-12-12T11:30:00.000Z');
// Get the difference in milliseconds
var diff = Math.abs( m1.diff(m2) );
// Format duration according your needs
console.log(moment.duration(diff).format("d [day] h [hrs]"));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```